# Simple ImageView Rotation

Tags: android, rotation, imageview

I am using this xml code to rotate an imageVeiw 180 degrees:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/keyP2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:rotation="180"
    android:maxWidth="125dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/image0_key" />
```

This works fine for android api version 11 and up, but `android:rotation="180"` is not supported below api 11. How can I rotate an imageView 180 degrees for below 11?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one. it work for me.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

  <rotate
      android:duration="2000"
      android:fromDegrees="0"
      android:pivotX="50%"
      android:pivotY="50%"
      android:toDegrees="360" >
  </rotate>

</set>
```

Save this file in resources under a folder named "anim".

> res/anim/rotate.xml

Within your activity. Add this code.

```
    Animation sampleFadeAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(PreviewImageActivity.this,R.anim.rotate);
    sampleFadeAnimation.setRepeatCount(1);
    yourImageView.startAnimation(sampleFadeAnimation);
```

Do some research you will get lot of properties to improve this rotate animation as your wish.

thanks...

Comment: I used this code and changed android:toDegrees="360" to android:toDegrees="180".  The animation does work but after the animation is complete, the imageview instantly switches back to its original position.  How can I make the imageview keep its position after the animation is played?

Comment: Ok I fixed my problem by adding this code after the animation: sampleFadeAnimation.setFillAfter(true);  This will keep the state of the any animation after it is completed.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try doing it programmatically by extending Animation. Off the top of my head something like:

```
RotateAnimation rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 350f, 15f, 15f);
rotateAnim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
rotateAnim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
rotateAnim.setDuration(700);

// Start the animation
final ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_ID);
imgView.startAnimation(rotateAnim);

// Stop when necessary
imgView.setAnimation(null);
```

Although I am not totally sure if RotateAnimation is supported pre-11. But you should be able to do it programmatically.

**edit:** refer to [Android Rotatable ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437732/android-rotatable-imageview) for additional options

Comment: Sorry that didn't work, that's just a quick try. I added a link that may help.

Comment: Thanks for your help but that is also for api 11 and up.  I might just have to create another set of images that are physically rotated in phothoshop.

Comment: Shoot, sorry man. Sorry those were no good. Maybe there's a way to find the bounds of the bitmap and just invert the greatest y axis by 180.