# to rotate whole imageViews in linearlayout in y axis

Tags: android, rotation, imageview, layer

There are many answers to how to rotate image in y axis. Also, there are answers to rotate layer in z axis.  However, what I want is to put many image side by side in a linear layer (or whatever), and rotate them in Y axis for a specific degree at once. just like the picture attached. In addition, the `ImageViews` still can be touched to invoke events.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you:

```
        ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(<yourView>,"rotationY",0f,180f);
        anim.setDuration(ANIMATION_TIME);
        anim.start();
```

Or maybe without animation you can use this answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437732/android-rotatable-imageview)

Comment: Thanks, but I just want images stay still in a specific degree. in addition, the link you had mentioned is only for a single imageview. it is not what i need.

Comment: Yep, the link is only for one, but I think you can extrapolate it to make it work with all the imageviews you have (in a loop or something similar)

Comment: thanks Ivan, could you please show me how?I am not that familiar for that.